# What kind of data should be used to demonstrate jack-knife usability?

Tags: jackknife

I tried to use jack-knife method to get the estimation of parameters of the model of the time series. The problem is, that if I use the least squares method, the parameters of a model are always the same or better than parameters obtained by jack-knife. 
My scheme is: 
1. obtain time series data 
2. use LS on all data to get parameters of the model (LS model) 
3. use jack-knife for obtained time series data from step 1 and estimate many models parameters
4. average the estimated parameters obtained in step 3 method to get the parameters of the one model
5. compare parameters from step 4 (jack-knifed model) with step 2 (LS model)

Are there some specific data that are suitable for jack-knife?